# Configuring keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, customization

I'm using OS X 10.7.2 and there are a couple keyboard shortcuts that are just driving me crazy - how do I change them?

- In **Chrome**, "Go Back" (or Forward) is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> (for forward), how do I change it to <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (for forward)
- In **Chrome**, search is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> .  I want it to be <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> (like in Windows or Linux)
- When working with text, going to the beginning or end of a line is <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, I want it to be <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (for right)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you intend your text shortcut to apply only to Chrome or be a system wide keyboard shortcut?

Comment: A system wide shortcut. Although this shortcut is last, it is the most important. That is, if you can't have overlapping keyboard shortcuts, I'll find another shortcut for go-back/forward in chrome.

Comment: You get both. App shortcuts override a system one by design. Open System Preferences and type this into the help menu search: "create keyboard shortcuts" - what step is failing you?

Comment: "You must type the command exactly as it appears in the application menu" - the last shortcut I want doesn't show in the application menu.

Comment: And, I changed "Back" and "Forward" as you suggest. In the menu, in chrome, I see the new shortcut, but it doesn't work using the keyboard. Ideas?

Comment: Command-left/right *does* go to the beginning/end of a line…

Comment: I restarted the computer and now everything works (!!). The back, the forward, the "jump to beginning of line". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can edit, create and enable/disable keyboard shortcuts using the **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab of the **Keyboard** preferences pane.
[image]

Comment: yes, I got that far... Can you be more specific on how I change the 3 shortcuts I asked about.